# File Tree / Viewer in PHP - files won't open unless they are in the base directory

Tags: php, jquery

I have searched a lot of things on this, and I can't seem to find a SIMPLE solution to my problem.

I am using [PHP File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/php-file-tree/) on our website, as it is pretty nifty and was the only simple tree view I could find. However, the problem I am having with it now is that the only files I can actually open must be at the root level. So if it's a file within a subfolder that I want to open, I get a "not found" error, where the url is something like "~/users/blah/root/file.txt" as opposed to "~/users/blah/root/subfolder/file.txt".

The call is simply:

```
echo php_file_tree(REALPATH."support");
```

and the part of the function that is doing the important work (where the problem lies, basically) is

```
        foreach( $file as $this_file ) {
        if( $this_file != "." && $this_file != ".." ) {
            if( is_dir("$directory/$this_file") ) {
                // Directory
                $php_file_tree .= "<li class=\"pft-directory\"><a href=\"#\">" . htmlspecialchars($this_file) . "</a>";
                $php_file_tree .= php_file_tree_dir("$directory/$this_file", $return_link ,$extensions, false);
                $php_file_tree .= "</li>";
            } else  {
                // File
                $link = $directory."/".$this_file;
                // Get extension (prepend 'ext-' to prevent invalid classes from extensions that begin with numbers)
                $ext = "ext-" . substr($this_file, strrpos($this_file, ".") + 1); 
                    $php_file_tree .= "<li class=\"pft-file " . strtolower($ext) . "\"><a href=".$this_file."\">" . htmlspecialchars($this_file) . "</a></li>";
                }
        }
    }
```

In the original code, $link is used in the href; however, I had problems with this as it was using an absolute path to a path that does not exist on the staging site that I am using. So with $this_file, the file will open but I know this is incorrect, as the if statement before the else takes care of the folders. However, $link does in fact contain the subfolder because it calls the directory it needs.

Is there any way of combining the two of these, basically so I can pass the subfolder as part of the file name in the href so it will be able to open? Has anybody had a problem like this before?

The whole set up needs to be dynamic, so no hard-coding of paths. The administrator will be able to delete and add folders and files as they require. There are loads of file explorers out there, but they don't look as plain as this treeview, and I'm an absolute novice to php and jQuery, so half the time I don't understand what is going on. However, I get this one but I don't know how to fix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: the only time I got it behaving correctly was when I essentially set the url in the function; however, that only worked on my local machine as I knew the paths for that. The server is different, and I'm not sure how to find the paths for that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `$directory` in ALL of your file path operations. It's missing in your `else` clause:

```
 $php_file_tree .= "..snip..."\"><a href=\"$directory/$this_file\">" ...snip...
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^--missing
```

Right now you're building a tree list, and for a file like `foo/bar/baz/file.txt` you end up generating

```
 <li><a href="file.txt">foo/bar/baz/file.txt</a>
```

when that link is clicked, you'll be looking for a `file.txt` in the same directory as the script itself, e.g. `http://example.com/script.php` will be linking to `http://example.com/file.txt`, instead of the `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.txt` you do want.

Comment: The problem with this, as I mentioned above, is the when I use $directory (which the $link variable includes), I get a path like `/home/me/public_html/website/content/folder/subfolder/TestFile.txt` instead of `/~me/website/content/folder/subfolder/TestFile.txt` - this means that even the files that do open when I don't include $directory won't open anymore. Do you know why this is? Obviously, including $directory does make the most sense, it won't work for me :(

Comment: you do have to translate your $dir into web-appropriate ones. a full absolute filesystem path has absolutely no use since it refers to directories OUTSIDE of your document root. you'll have to keep track of where your document root ends in `$directory`, and output only the web-allowable portion. but regardless, this is still your problem: you're not including ANY path information in your original links.

Comment: I do understand that it's my problem - my main issue was with how to get the paths. So would you think that trimming down the `$directory` variable will help? How much of the link is actually web-allowable? Do you think from content on is enough? As said, I'm so new to this so if I sound like I haven't a clue, it's because I don't have a clue but I am trying to learn.